# Knockout.js: click event is not triggered inside a foreach loop data-bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm working with Knockout.js and asp .net mvc. The problem with below code is that "removeItem" event is not triggered. I've been struggling with this for days and tried different alternatives but nothing seems to work. There are no javascript errors on the page, it loads correctly but when I click on the button nothing happens. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: categories" id="tablebody">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="table-cell-id">
                            <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="small" data-bind="text: Name, attr: { href: $parent.onViewDetails($data) }"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="small text-nowrap" data-bind="text: Code, attr: { href: $parent.onViewDetails($data) }"></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: CreationDateInFormat"></td>
                        <td class="text-center text-nowrap" data-bind="text: CreatedByName"></td>
                        <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: ModificationDateInFormat"></td>
                        <td class="text-center text-nowrap" data-bind="text: ModifiedByName"></td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="label label-default" data-bind="text: StatusName"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-cell-actions">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button class="item-action" type="button" id="itemOptions1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="itemOptions1">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="btn btn-dropdown" data-bind="attr: { href: $parent.onViewDetails($data) }">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open offset-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            Details
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="btn btn-dropdown" data-bind="attr: { href: $parent.onEditItem($data) }">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil offset-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            Edit
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dropdown" data-bind="click: removeItem">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign offset-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            Delete
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

JS:

```
<script>
        function MyViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            var categories = [];
            var arrayOfCategories = @Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model);

            var Item = function (name, code, categoryId, creationDateInFormat, createdByName, modificationDateInFormat, modifiedByName, status) {
                this.Name = name;
                this.Code = code;
                this.CategoryId = categoryId;
                this.CreationDateInFormat = creationDateInFormat;
                this.CreatedByName = createdByName;
                this.ModificationDateInFormat = modificationDateInFormat;
                this.ModifiedByName = modifiedByName;
                this.StatusName = status;
                this.removeItem = function () {
                    alert(this.Name);
                }
            };

            arrayOfCategories.forEach(function(element) {
                categories.push(
                    new Item(element.Name,
                        element.Code,
                        element.CategoryId,
                        element.CreationDateInFormat,
                        element.CreatedByName,
                        element.ModificationDateInFormat,
                        element.ModifiedByName,
                        element.Status.Name
                    )
                );
            });


            var pageUrls = {};
            pageUrls.editUrl = '@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = 0 })';
            pageUrls.detailsUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", new { id = 0 })';

            self.categories = ko.observableArray(categories);

            self.onEditItem = function(data) {
                return pageUrls.editUrl.replace('0', data.CategoryId);
            };

            self.onViewDetails = function(data) {
                return pageUrls.detailsUrl.replace('0', data.CategoryId);
            };
        }

        var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    </script>
```

Comment: Which button? There is more than one in your code. Also have you tried creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for you answer @MartinBrown. I noticed that nothing was working for that delete button because of my reference to bootstrap-iu.js reference. When I removed it, my code worked prefectly

Answer (score 1):

I *did* get errors copying your code to a snippet.

1. Is your `<tbody>` element inside a `<table>`? Table configurations that do not respect the spec often don't get rendered correctly.
2. Your click handler needs to be correctly bound to a category using either `.bind(this)` or some `var self = this` pattern.

Fixing these does get your button to work as intended (the category name is alerted).

```js
function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  var categories = [];
  var arrayOfCategories = [{
    Code: 1,
    Name: "Some name",
    Status: {}
  }]

  var Item = function(name, code, categoryId, creationDateInFormat, createdByName, modificationDateInFormat, modifiedByName, status) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Code = code;
    this.CategoryId = categoryId;
    this.CreationDateInFormat = creationDateInFormat;
    this.CreatedByName = createdByName;
    this.ModificationDateInFormat = modificationDateInFormat;
    this.ModifiedByName = modifiedByName;
    this.StatusName = status;
    this.removeItem = function() {
      alert(this.Name);
    }.bind(this)
  };

  arrayOfCategories.forEach(function(element) {
    categories.push(
      new Item(element.Name,
        element.Code,
        element.CategoryId,
        element.CreationDateInFormat,
        element.CreatedByName,
        element.ModificationDateInFormat,
        element.ModifiedByName,
        element.Status.Name
      )
    );
  });


  var pageUrls = {};
  pageUrls.editUrl = '@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = 0 })';
  pageUrls.detailsUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", new { id = 0 })';

  self.categories = ko.observableArray(categories);

  self.onEditItem = function(data) {
    return pageUrls.editUrl.replace('0', data.CategoryId);
  };

  self.onViewDetails = function(data) {
    return pageUrls.detailsUrl.replace('0', data.CategoryId);
  };
}

var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: categories" id="tablebody">
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell-id">
        <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="small" data-bind="text: Name, attr: { href: $parent.onViewDetails($data) }"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="small text-nowrap" data-bind="text: Code, attr: { href: $parent.onViewDetails($data) }"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: CreationDateInFormat"></td>
      <td class="text-center text-nowrap" data-bind="text: CreatedByName"></td>
      <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: ModificationDateInFormat"></td>
      <td class="text-center text-nowrap" data-bind="text: ModifiedByName"></td>
      <td>
        <span class="label label-default" data-bind="text: StatusName"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="table-cell-actions">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="item-action" type="button" id="itemOptions1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="itemOptions1">
            <li>
              <a class="btn btn-dropdown" data-bind="attr: { href: $parent.onViewDetails($data) }">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open offset-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> Details
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="btn btn-dropdown" data-bind="attr: { href: $parent.onEditItem($data) }">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil offset-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-dropdown" data-bind="click: removeItem">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign offset-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            Delete
                                        </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it is inside a <table>. Regarding #2 i've tried that too. Anyway, thanks for your reply but I noticed that nothing was working for that delete button because of my reference to bootstrap-iu.js reference. When I removed it, my code workd prefectly.